# Expanding macro in renewcommand

Tags: macros, glossaries

Good evening, or morning, depending on where you are.

## Background

I have been tinkering with an idea for how I can make my LaTeX macros easily accessible in for markdown (through MathJax) without lowering my standards in LaTeX. Specifically, I want to be able to write equations that are <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> ready. Moreover, since I have to think about writing a thesis I want it to flawlessly fall into my glossary and index system.

I have achieved a minimal working example using the rather exhaustive approach:

1. Define notation using `\newcommand`, and make a "dummy" copy to be used in glossary definition.
2. Define glossary entries where the label is the same as the notation equivalent.
3. Redefine notation definitions such that `\Hamiltonian |--> \glssymbol{Hamiltonian}\index{Hamiltonian}`

## Minimal Example

Typeset command (terminal):

```
filename=asdf.tex
pdflatex ${filename}
makeglossaries  -l ${filename%%.*}
makeindex  ${filename/.*/.idx}
pdflatex ${filename}
pdflatex ${filename}
```

LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{memoir}
%
\title{This is a test}
\author{Ola}
% 1 ************** N O T A T I O N -- D E F I N I T I O N ******************* %
\usepackage{amsmath}
%% H
\newcommand{\Hamiltonian}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{H}}}% <-------------- Definition
\let\OldHamiltonian\Hamiltonian% <--------------------- Used in glossary symbol
%% L
\newcommand{\Lagrangian}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{L}}}% <--------------- Definition
\let\OldLagrangian\Lagrangian% <----------------------- Used in glossary symbol
%% P
\newcommand{\vecGeneralMomentum}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{p}}}% <------- Definition
\let\OldVecGeneralMomentum\vecGeneralMomentum% <----- Used in glossary symbol
%% Q
\newcommand{\vecGeneralPosition}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{q}}}% <-------- Definition
\let\OldVecGeneralPosition\vecGeneralPosition% <------- Used in glossary symbol
% 2 ************ G L O S S A R Y -- D E F I N I T I O N ********************* %
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[%
  nopostdot,%
  nonumberlist,%
  toc,%
  section,%
  acronym,%
]{glossaries}
%% H
\newglossaryentry{Hamiltonian}{% <--------- The same as in \newcommand
  type=main,%
  name={Hamiltonian function},%
  symbol={\OldHamiltonian},% <------------- "dummy" copy of command
  description={Hamiltonian function},%
}%
%% L
\newglossaryentry{Lagrangian}{% <---------- The same as in \newcommand
  type=main,%
  sort={Lagrangian},%
  name={Lagrangian function},%
  symbol={\OldLagrangian},% <-------------- "dummy" copy of command
  description={Lagrangian function},%
}%
%% P
\newglossaryentry{vecGeneralPosition}{% <-- The same as in \newcommand
  type=main,%
  sort={Pos},%
  name={position vector},%
  symbol={\OldVecGeneralPosition},% <------ "dummy" copy of command
  description={Generalised position vector},%
}%
%% Q
\newglossaryentry{vecGeneralMomentum}{% <--- The same as in \newcommand
  type=main,%
  name={momentum vector},%
  symbol={\OldVecGeneralMomentum},% <------- "dummy" copy of command
  description={Generalised momentum vector},%
}%
% ... Prettify the glossary table...
\newglossarystyle{mylong2col}{%
  % put glossary in a longtable
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {%
     \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
     \setlength\LTright{0pt}
     \begin{longtable}[l]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l|p{\glsdescwidth}@{}}%
    }%
    {\end{longtable}}%
  % Set the table header
   \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
    \bfseries Symbol &%
    \bfseries Description
    \\ \hline \endhead}%
   \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
   \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[1]{%
      \glsentryitem{##1}%                              Entry number if required
      \glstarget{##1}{\glossentrysymbol{##1}}%                           Symbol
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
        \tabularnewline % end of row
   }%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}
%
\makeglossaries
\makeindex
%
% 3 ************ R E D E F I N E  --  D E F I N I T I O N S ****************** %
%% H
\renewcommand{\Hamiltonian}{\glssymbol{Hamiltonian}\index{\glsentryfirst{Hamiltonian}}}
%% L
\renewcommand{\Lagrangian}{\glssymbol{Lagrangian}\index{\glsentryfirst{Lagrangian}}}
%% P
\renewcommand{\vecGeneralMomentum}{\glssymbol{vecGeneralMomentum}\index{\glsentryfirst{vecGeneralMomentum}}}
%% Q
\renewcommand{\vecGeneralPosition}{\glssymbol{vecGeneralPosition}\index{\glsentryfirst{vecGeneralPosition}}}
% ===================== B E G I N   D O C U M E N T  ======================== %
\begin{document}
%
% ----------------------- F R O N T - M A T T E R --------------------------- %
\frontmatter
%
\maketitle
%
\printglossary[style=mylong2col]
%
% ------------------------ M A I N - M A T T E R ---------------------------- %
%
\mainmatter
%
\chapter{Classical Mechanics}
$$
  \Hamiltonian := \mathrm{d}\left(\vecGeneralPosition \vecGeneralMomentum \right) - \Lagrangian
$$
% -------------------------- A P P E N D I X -------------------------------- %
\appendix
%
% ------------------------- B A C K - M A T T E R --------------------------- %
\backmatter
\printindex
%
\end{document}
```

## Question

I want to replace the third step above with an automated loop using the features of the glossaries package.

I was planning to use `forallglsentries`, i.e. something along the lines of:

```
\forallglsentries[main]{\glslabel}{%
  \renewcommand{\glslabel}{\glssymbol{\glslabel}\index{\glsentryfirst{\glslabel}}}
}%
```

However, here I am not able to get `\csname \oldSymbol\endcsname` to work, which is necessary because `\oldSymbol` expands to "Hamiltonian", whereas `renewcommand` needs "\Hamiltonian".

Any ideas for how to approach this situation is greatly appreciated.

---

### Bonus question

I have a suspicion that "step 2" is redundant as well, but I do not see an obvious way around it without introducing circular references as I demand that the name given in the definition (`\newcommand`) should be the one that is used in the text as well.

Is there a way for me to "copy/expand" the content of a newcommand into the `symbol` key of the glossaryentry?

Comment: This is an expansion issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual issue with `\renewcommand` and constructing command sequences is the missing expansion with `\csname ...\endcsname`, so use `\expandafter\renewcommand\csname\oldSymbol\endcsname{...}`

However, this would not be sufficient, unless the `\oldSymbol` value is 'pre'-expanded before it can be used inside `\glssymbol` etc., otherwise, it would either cause errors or the wrong value (i.e. always the last one in the `\forallglsentries` - loop) will be applied.

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{memoir}
%
\title{This is a test}
\author{Ola}
% 1 ************** N O T A T I O N -- D E F I N I T I O N ******************* %
\usepackage{amsmath}
%% H
\newcommand{\Hamiltonian}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{H}}}% <-------------- Definition
\let\OldHamiltonian\Hamiltonian% <--------------------- Used in glossary symbol
%% L
\newcommand{\Lagrangian}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{L}}}% <--------------- Definition
\let\OldLagrangian\Lagrangian% <----------------------- Used in glossary symbol
%% P
\newcommand{\vecGeneralMomentum}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{p}}}% <------- Definition
\let\OldVecGeneralMomentum\vecGeneralMomentum% <----- Used in glossary symbol
%% Q
\newcommand{\vecGeneralPosition}{\ensuremath{\mathbf{q}}}% <-------- Definition
\let\OldVecGeneralPosition\vecGeneralPosition% <------- Used in glossary symbol
% 2 ************ G L O S S A R Y -- D E F I N I T I O N ********************* %
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[%
  nopostdot,%
  nonumberlist,%
  toc,%
  section,%
  acronym,%
]{glossaries}
%% H
\newglossaryentry{Hamiltonian}{% <--------- The same as in \newcommand
  type=main,%
  name={Hamiltonian function},%
  symbol={\OldHamiltonian},% <------------- "dummy" copy of command
  description={Hamiltonian function},%
}%
%% L
\newglossaryentry{Lagrangian}{% <---------- The same as in \newcommand
  type=main,%
  sort={Lagrangian},%
  name={Lagrangian function},%
  symbol={\OldLagrangian},% <-------------- "dummy" copy of command
  description={Lagrangian function},%
}%
%% P
\newglossaryentry{vecGeneralPosition}{% <-- The same as in \newcommand
  type=main,%
  sort={Pos},%
  name={position vector},%
  symbol={\OldVecGeneralPosition},% <------ "dummy" copy of command
  description={Generalised position vector},%
}%
%% Q
\newglossaryentry{vecGeneralMomentum}{% <--- The same as in \newcommand
  type=main,%
  name={momentum vector},%
  symbol={\OldVecGeneralMomentum},% <------- "dummy" copy of command
  description={Generalised momentum vector},%
}%
% ... Prettify the glossary table...
\newglossarystyle{mylong2col}{%
  % put glossary in a longtable
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
    {%
     \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
     \setlength\LTright{0pt}
     \begin{longtable}[l]{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l|p{\glsdescwidth}@{}}%
    }%
    {\end{longtable}}%
  % Set the table header
   \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
    \bfseries Symbol &%
    \bfseries Description
    \\ \hline \endhead}%
   \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%
   \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[1]{%
      \glsentryitem{##1}%                              Entry number if required
      \glstarget{##1}{\glossentrysymbol{##1}}%                           Symbol
        & \glossentrydesc{##1}% Description
        \tabularnewline % end of row
   }%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%
}
%
\makeglossaries
\makeindex
%
% 3 ************ R E D E F I N E  --  D E F I N I T I O N S ****************** %
%% H
%\renewcommand{\Hamiltonian}{\glssymbol{Hamiltonian}\index{\glsentryfirst{Hamiltonian}}}
%% L
%\renewcommand{\Lagrangian}{\glssymbol{Lagrangian}\index{\glsentryfirst{Lagrangian}}}
%% P
%\renewcommand{\vecGeneralMomentum}{\glssymbol{vecGeneralMomentum}\index{\glsentryfirst{vecGeneralMomentum}}}
%% Q
%\renewcommand{\vecGeneralPosition}{\glssymbol{vecGeneralPosition}\index{\glsentryfirst{vecGeneralPosition}}}
% ===================== B E G I N   D O C U M E N T  ======================== %
\begin{document}
%
% ----------------------- F R O N T - M A T T E R --------------------------- %
\frontmatter
%
\maketitle
%
\printglossary[style=mylong2col]
%
% ------------------------ M A I N - M A T T E R ---------------------------- %
%
\mainmatter

\def\oldSymbol{}
\newcommand{\redefinethestuff}[1]{%
   \expandafter\renewcommand\csname#1\endcsname{\glssymbol{#1}\index{\glsentryfirst{#1}}}
}
\forallglsentries[main]{\oldSymbol}{%
  \expandafter\redefinethestuff\expandafter{\oldSymbol}%
}%

\chapter{Classical Mechanics}
\[
  \Hamiltonian := \mathrm{d}\left(\vecGeneralPosition \vecGeneralMomentum \right) - \Lagrangian
\]
% -------------------------- A P P E N D I X -------------------------------- %
\appendix
%
% ------------------------- B A C K - M A T T E R --------------------------- %
\backmatter
\printindex
%
\end{document}
```

Please don't use `$$...$$` but `\[ ... \]` instead!